# cannot invoke initializer for type 'float2' with a argument list of type 'CGPoint'

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I am getting this error, this is my code below, I have import simd but it doesn't work.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = panningTouch {
        let displacement = float2(touch.location(in: view)) - float2(touch.previousLocation(in: view))
        panCamera(displacement)   
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `panCamera` and what is the data type of its argument?

Comment: the argument is float2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, `simd.float2` doesn't have an initializer that takes a `CGPoint`. However, you can add your own:

```
extension float2 {
    init(_ point: CGPoint) {
        self.init(Float(point.x), Float(point.y))
    }
}
```